# aws s3 bucket does not recognize index.html in sub directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My folder structure on aws s3 is as shown below:

src
----> index.html

Now in  **static website hosting** setting in , I am trying to set

```
http://www.website.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/src/index.html
```

inside **index document** field. Somehow , it is giving me

`The IndexDocument Suffix is not well formed` error. How can I solve this error?

Comment: Index Document is a **name**.  It is not a **path** or a **URL**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20269943/1695906. What are you trying to accomplish, here?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have bucket name 'www.m.xyz.com'. Inside that bucket I have `src` folder. Inside that folder I have `index.html` file. Now I am not able to get that index.html file as it is inside src folder. So how should I point it ?

Comment: the index document is a folder-level entity that is looked up for each folder.  If your index document is `index.html` then  `GET /` → S3 looks for object `index.html`; `GET /photos/cats/funny` → looks for object `photos/cats/funny` and if not found then it looks for object `photos/cats/funny/` and if not found it finally looks for object  `photos/cats/funny/index.html`.  It is not a specification of a single document for the entire bucket, but rather a single *name* to search for in any request that looks like a request for a folder... it looks for that file inside the folder.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have already put `index.html` in `index document` field in `static website hosting`. Then why it is not able to load it ?

Answer (score 3):

Agreed. It appears that it is not possible to include a slash in the Index document name (eg `src/index.htm`).

It appears that the **Index document** is relative to a given path, so that:

- `/` defaults to `/index.html`
- `/src/` defaults to `/src/index.html`
- etc

A workaround could be to have an `index.htm` file that does a redirect to `src/`, which will then correctly default to `src/index.htm`.

Alternatively, you could put **Amazon CloudFront** in front of S3 and define the origin as being the `src` path.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I put `src` in `origin path` in cloudFront. Still it is not able to find index.html

Comment: not origin, but at `Default root object`