# Having trouble understanding how to host a static website on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Sorry if this isn't the right place for this but I can't find the answer to this anywhere. I've never used aws before and I want to use it to host a static website that I built. I bought a domain name and followed the documentation using their example index.html document and have everything working. Now I'm trying to upload the documents for my actual document that has a structure like this:

MySite

-assets

--images

-src

--index.html

--style.css

I cannot figure out how to get it to go to my index.html file in the src folder. Please help me

EDIT: Forgot to add that the error I keep getting is: "The IndexDocument Suffix is not well formed"

Comment: This is the error message you would get when configuring the index document as `src/index.html`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264928/s3-static-website-index-document

Answer (score 0):

Hi it will always read from the root of the bucket. You'll want to have index.html in the root not in the src folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I have it in the root folder will it still have access to the style .css file and assets folder?

Comment: As long they maintain the correct relative position to the index.html :)